# Swift google firebase VisionTextDetector showing Use of undeclared type

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to implement Google Firebase CoreML for text detection. Here, I installed a list of pods into my project but I still get `Use of undeclared type 'VisionTextDetector'`. How to fix this?

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionFaceModel'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionBarcodeModel'
pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionLabelModel'
```

Below is my class file:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class TextViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var vision = Vision.vision()
    var textDetector: VisionTextDetector?  // Error: Use of undeclared type 'VisionTextDetector'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/recognize-text) didn't mentioned about the actual framework to be imported which is `FirebaseMLVision`, so with or without "Firebase", you much import actual "MLVision" framework. Just add below line on the top of your `class` file.

`import FirebaseMLVision`

Let me know, if you still face that error!

Comment: I have same issue, and FirebaseMLVision is already imported.. still the same issue 'Use of undeclared type 'VisionTextDetector''

Answer (score 0):

`VisionTextDetector` is no more supported so you have to use `VisionTextRecognizer`. no need to import `FirebaseMLVision`